# django convert list of objects to list of primary keys

Tags: django

As the title says I have a list of Django objects and I want to get a list of primary keys.  What is the best way of doing this?

I know I could do

```
my_list = []
for item in object_list:
    my_list.append(item.pk)
```

but was wondering if there is Django or Python specific way of doing this better.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One more pythonic way to start with is:

```
my_list = [item.pk for item in object_list]
```

A full django way:

```
my_list = object_list.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Comment: ...and to get a real `List()`, the latter needs to be wrapped in to `list()` call.